# Is there a better way to read one xml value from the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml

I'm currently using this code fragment to retrieve the one xml value that will be returned from my scalar query.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        SqlXml xml = reader.GetSqlXml(0);
        XmlSchema xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(xml.CreateReader(), validationEvent);
        break;
    }
}
```

I would prefer to use `sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`  but it seems that to do that means bringing back to the xml into a `String` which seems wrongheaded to me, since I'm not interested in having a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by running ExecuteNonQuery, you can only return an int (the return value of the stored procedure).  Except for ExecuteScalar, you have 2 options:

1. ExecuteXMLReader
2. Use an output parameter (I would prefer to use Scalar over this)

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation on SqlDbType.Xml

> An XML value. Obtain the XML as a
>   string using the GetValue method or
>   Value property, or as an XmlReader by
>   calling the CreateReader method.

So you will either end up with your existing code, or get the xml returned as a string with ExecuteScalar, which you must parse into an xml object.